# How do I borrow a String as mutable to push itself to itself?

Tags: memory, rust

I am trying to solve a problem from [r/dailyprogrammer](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer) and have run into a problem with borrowing a `String` as mutable.

I'm trying to see if a `String` has been "looped" around. Comparing "hello" to "llohe" would return true whereas "hello" to "oelhl" would not. My strategy was to double one string and see if it contains the other one:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = String::from("hello");
    let mut y = String::from("llohe");
    println!("{}", compare(x, &mut y));
}

fn compare(x: String, y: &mut String) -> bool {
    y.push_str(y.as_str());
    if y.contains(&x) {
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*y` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
8 |     y.push_str(y.as_str());
  |     ^^--------^-^^^^^^^^^^
  |     | |        |
  |     | |        immutable borrow occurs here
  |     | immutable borrow later used by call
  |     mutable borrow occurs here
```

I don't know where the heck I'm doing that. I am trying to become friends with the compiler, but it is quite prickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to have a `mut` ref at all, you can skip all that:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = String::from("hello");
    let y = String::from("llohe");
    println!("{}", compare(&x, &y));
}

fn compare(x: &String, y: &String) -> bool {
    let mut z = y.clone();
    
    z.push_str(y.as_str());
    
    // You don't need to wrap a boolean in an if and return booleans,
    // just let the result of the test be the return value
    z.contains(x)
}
```

The `as_str()` function needs a reference to the string, but as you're holding a mutable reference that violates the borrow checker rules. Rust just isn't comfortable with all those references co-existing.

This is likely because you're asking to append to a string a copy of the string you're in the process of appending to, which could lead to problems. `as_str` needs the string to be stable, `push_str` needs to be able to change the string. They can't inter-operate like that.

You can side-step this by cloning the string:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = String::from("hello");
    let mut y = String::from("llohe");
    println!("{}", compare(x, &mut y));
}

fn compare(x: String, y: &mut String) -> bool {
    y.push_str(y.clone().as_str());
    if y.contains(&x) {
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to borrow a `String` as mutable to push itself to itself. Instead, you have to first clone the string, and then push the cloned version to itself:

```rust
y.push_str(y.clone().as_str());
```

However, in your case you do not need to pass a mutable reference to `y`, because you are not modifying it. Instead, you can create a new string with [`String::repeat()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.repeat):

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = String::from("hello");
    let y = String::from("llohe");
    println!("{}", compare(x, y));
}

fn compare(x: String, y: String) -> bool {
    y.repeat(2).contains(&x)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As an answer to the problem instead of the question, you don't need heap allocation at all; iterators provide enough capability here:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = "hello";
    let y = "llehe";
    println!("{}", compare(x, y));
}

fn compare(x: &str, y: &str) -> bool {
    let x = x.as_bytes();
    let mut y = y.as_bytes().iter().chain(y.as_bytes());

    loop {
        let yy = y.clone();
        if x.iter().eq(yy.take(x.len())) {
            return true; // or break true;
        }
        if y.next().is_none() {
            return false; // or break false;
        }
    }
}
```